# Resolving path aliases in JSON file with webpack

Tags: webpack

How do I make it so webpack will resolve the URL inside `manifest.json`?

I am trying to create a `manifest.json` file so I can make my site a PWA. I currently have it so I can load the json file and the PWA manifest works, until I try setting the icons. The image URL wont resolve and replace with the image's content hash (eg `localhost:8080/images/2ca93c31fcv7dhd565e5.png`

Here is the `manifest.json` (name is content hashed) in the browser debug window, the icon URL does not get replaced.

[[image: 1]

This is the `webpack.config.js` file

[image]